# Stock LG-D500 Bootloop. Factory Reset only temporarily fixes

Tags: boot, boot-loop, crashes

I checked a few of the other links/threads. Mostly it seems like people changed something (ROM, or went in a did something to permissions) whereas my phone has no changes made by me. There are/were apps on the phone.

The phone started acting up awhile ago with lagging (if this is relevant) and I would have to restart it every couple days.

Now the apps are crashing and I wasn't able to open almost anything. Like Alarm Clock, Google Search, BaconReader, etc. I was able to open Pandora. When I tried to restart it it went into bootloop. I tried to fix it myself by searching Google and Factory Reset and Wipe dalvik-cache seemed to be the answer, however I could not for the life of me find Wipe dalvik-cache on the LG-D500. I did a factory reset and that let the phone turn back on. However soon the same apps were crashing and the non opening issue was back. Even System UI crashed on the last reset attempt.

If I hold power and down volume it *only* goes to factory reset. I can't figure out how to wipe the cache or anything like that.

**Apps (now they are gone due to reset)**

- BaconReader
- Candy and Soda Crush
- CM Lock, Cleaner
- Pandora
- Moon Reader+
- Chess.com

What can I do? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!